# Maven Path Variable Issue

Tags: maven, path, system-variable

I am having issues running `mvn --version` anywhere outside of C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin.  If I run `mvn --version` inside the apache-maven/bin folder I get the version number, however if I run it anywhere outside it says will not recognize `mvn`.

Am I missing something in my path variables?

My System Variables:

```
M2 = %M2_HOME%\bin
M2_HOME = C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.1
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51
```

I appended

```
Path = ; %M2%
```

My User Variables:

```
M2 = %M2_HOME%\bin
M2_HOME = C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.1
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define variables before you use them. Change the order of the first two lines in your first example, and set `PATH`, not `Path`.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it, I tried setting M2_HOME first by deleting variable M2.  I could be misunderstanding, but I am setting the variables through the System Properties>Environment Variables and not through the cmd line which seems to ignore the order.